# Concat data with different queries

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I fetched data with query and transformed custom array with transformResponse and same do with another query.
How I can get the first query data and concat with second data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do so in your component, there is really no need to do that in a central location and the cache is really just "per request", no merging possible there.

Keep queries up for whatever you want to display right now. There is only so much space on the screen.

Even infinite scrolling can be done with 3 useXQuery calls if your page size is bigger than what fits on one screen.